# Member count discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a question with my member counter code. What can I do, because is is not updating itself when someone join or leave. But when I restart bot it update.

```
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('1005227479906144286');
  setInterval(() => {
    const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('1005504987528450182')
    channel.setName(`᲼᲼Nariai: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}᲼᲼`)
  }, 600000);
});
```

Comment: The fact that there's two times the word `cache` in there, probably has something to do with it.

Comment: What intents have you enabled and what's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(() => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('1005227479906144286');
    const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('1005504987528450182')
    channel.setName(`᲼᲼Nariai: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}᲼᲼`)
  }, 600000);
});
```

Maybe like this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).